# node.js Unexpected identifier anywhere the file is called

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm writing an app in node.js and recently i had an unexpected error on all my project.

When i try to call a model in my browser , i always get a

`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

On any function called in my code .

For example, if i go on "/session/new",

my code is :

```
app.get('/session/new',function (req,res) {
    res.render('sessions/new',{locals:{
        redir:req.query.redir
    }});
});
```

and i get an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.Function (unknown source)
at Object.render (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/jade/0.6.3/package/lib/jade.js:267:14)
at ServerResponse.render (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/1.0.7/package/lib/express/view.js:334:22)
at ServerResponse.render (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/1.0.7/package/lib/express/view.js:344:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/geraudmathe/Desktop/nodemongo/app.js:133:6)
at param (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.5.2/package/lib/connect/middleware/router.js:145:21)
at pass (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.5.2/package/lib/connect/middleware/router.js:161:10)
at Object.router [as handle] (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.5.2/package/lib/connect/middleware/router.js:167:6)
at next (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.5.2/package/lib/connect/index.js:232:23)
at next (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/0.5.2/package/lib/connect/index.js:234:17)
```

where /nodemongo/app.js:133:6 is res.render in my code.

It happen no matter what code i call.

I'm lost ...

Comment: It looks like an error in your jade template. Can you post that?

Comment: You're right that was a formatting error in jade. Tanks

Comment: But what was the error? A non-existent variable? Indentation problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found this issue to be a different sum of things, it could be that you have an unsupported attr on a jade template call, eg:

```
<img src="something.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" />
```

It took me forever to find this out, and the only way to do this would be to start taking lumps of code out of the jade template file you are calling in your res.render.

Good luck, this error can be a lot of things.

Update: http://groups.google.com/group/express-js/browse_thread/thread/b9acfc80f6acb63b?pli=1

You can use `jade index.jade` to debug the file

Comment: I had a similar issue trying to use a meta refresh tag in my `.jade` template. I resolved by using the literal html instead

Comment: Using jade index.jade (or whatever template your editing) is a life-saver as far as getting meaningful errors is concerned

Comment: on my case, this was happening when i update Jade. In one component, I forgot one comma between the attributes...

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was an issue with the syntax

I had:

```
input.search-query(placeholder="Search" type="text")
```

It should have been

```
input.search-query(placeholder="Search", type="text")
```

Comment: Yup, I had missing commas between attributes in two `link` tags.

Comment: Same here. IMO these commas should be optional as HTML doesn't use commas in the attributes either

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was resolved by removing the last backslash in this line...

```
<a href="" onclick="window.open(\'http://www.facebook.com/' + friend.uid + '\');">
```

Answer (score 0):

On any `script` or `style` tags make sure you change them to `script.` and `style.`

According to the Jade updates you have to do that. I was having problems with Google Analytics code until I read that on the Git repo

Example:

```
script.
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-11111111-1', 'yourdomain.com');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Make sure the spacing and such is actually indented one space from your stuff